# PL SQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure but i don't understand why is it not working . But it gives me : "Error(6,25): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

This code works as expected

```
DECLARE
v_price Car.price%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT price INTO v_price
FROM Car
WHERE model = 'VW';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_price);
END;
```

but this one gives me error :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getPret AS
v_price Car.price%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT price INTO v_price
FROM Car
WHERE model = 'VW'
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_price);
END;
```

Comment: missing semicolon after model = 'VW'

Comment: your select query lacks a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sarit Adhikari is correct, you are missing a semicolon on:

```
WHERE model = 'VW'
```

Answer (score -1):

The select statement in the second  procedure doesnt end correctly ... So u r receiving this error , introduce semi colon next to where condition...  This will help to resolve the issue